# Open Ubuntu MATE 16.04 in CLI

Tags: boot, ubuntu-mate

I need to start a Raspberry Pi 3 in CLI mode. I looked it up, and found instructions for editing `/etc/default/grub`. However, there is no file `/etc/default/grub` on my system.

Comment: Read this carefully and follow instructions http://ask.xmodulo.com/boot-into-command-line-ubuntu-debian.html

Comment: `you could also do it in raspi-config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to edit `/etc/default/grub` with Ubuntu MATE. To boot in console mode, this command suffices:

`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Comment: If you could mark it as answering your question, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: (sigh!) Happy to, but don't know how to do that.